# VS Code and Java

Tags: java, android, visual-studio-code

I am totally new to [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and as I want to start learning Java for Android development. I saw that the Java language [was supported](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview) by the VS Code IDE so that was good news. Ok but how would one exactly approach developing anything in Java via VS Code? I mean what is the build process for compiling anything I write in Java? Would I need to write some special tasks.json or?

What I would like to start with is a simple "console" like Java application build with VS Code. I would appreciate any information regarding this topic, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install the java language support by pressing F1 and entering `ext install java`.

You will need to install maeven or gradle (or ant?) for your build process.